# analyse the content and extracting link and images in php

Tags: php, html, class, filter

you may have seen how facebook analyses the content and extracting links images and videos

when we insert something like this

```
this is an example text which is linked linke this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
and i like it so much like this picture     http://stackoverflow.com/img.png
```

it changes into this

```
    this is an example text which is linked linke this   
<a href='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'>
    and i like it so much like this picture   
 <img src='http://stackoverflow.com/img.png'>
```

now i want to do exactly the same and analyse my content and produce an enriched content .

how can I do such a thing in php ? is there any class ready for it ?

Answer (score 1):

These are two functions that works properly and are tested by me.

```
function isImage($url) {
    if (substr($url, 0, 7) == 'http://') {
        $i = str_ireplace('http://', '', $url); // delete first part
        $i = explode('/', $i); // divide link into parts
        $end = end($i); // get the last part
        $ex = explode('.', $end); // get the extension if exists so for 'image.jpg' $ex = jpg
        if (count($ex) === 2) {
            $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'); // allowed image extensions
            foreach ($allowed as $a) {
                if ($ex = $a) {
                    # Is an image
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            # It's an url
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        # It's not even a link
        return false;
    }
}

function isLink($url) {
    if (substr($url, 0, 7) == 'http://') {
        $i = str_ireplace('http://', '', $url); // delete first part
        $i = explode('/', $url); // divide link into parts
        $end = end($i); // get the last part
        $ex = explode('.', $end); // get the extension if exists so for 'image.jpg' $ex = jpg
        return (count($ex) == 0) ? true : false;
    } else {
        # It's not even a link
        return false;
    }
}

$image = isImage($input); // true
$link = isLink($input); // false
var_dump($image, $link);
```

Examples (`isLink()`):

- 'google.com' = false (*)
- 'http://google.com' = true
- 'http://google.com/image.png' = false

Examples (`isImage()`):

- 'google.com' = false
- 'google.com/image.png' = false (*)
- 'http://google.com/image.png' = true
- 'http://google.com/view/model/controller' = false

(*) = This because it checks if the link has `http://` as prefix. If you don't want this to happen, then here's the functions:

```
function isImage($url) {
    $i = explode('/', $i); // divide link into parts
    $end = end($i); // get the last part
    $ex = explode('.', $end); // get the extension if exists so for 'image.jpg' $ex = jpg
    if (count($ex) === 2) {
        $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'); // allowed image extensions
        foreach ($allowed as $a) {
            if ($ex = $a) {
                # Is an image
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        # It's an url
        return false;
    }
}

function isLink($url) {
    $i = explode('/', $url); // divide link into parts
    $end = end($i); // get the last part
    $ex = explode('.', $end); // get the extension if exists so for 'image.jpg' $ex = jpg
    return (count($ex) == 0) ? true : false;
}
```

And then you can use it as:

```
if (isLink($url)) { echo "<a href=\"$url\">$url</a>"; }
if (isImage($url)) { echo "<img src=\"$url\" alt=\"image\">"; }
```

Comment: thanks , but consider im entering a text contains some links and images , then how can i change it ?

Comment: i updated my question , maybe this way of presenting is better .

Comment: Updated my answer (see the last 3 lines).

Comment: Oh hell no. Now i got your question. Well, you'll have to check every word in the text. It's way too haevy for a script. I suggest you to insert some kind of bbcode. Also consider that links are clickable even if you don't enter the <a> tag. Do you really want that every image is shown without control? I don't think so. That's why you need of some bbcode system: http://forums.yessoftware.com/posts.php?post_id=77123

Comment: There's nothing in your code to parse a text and replace links

Comment: Also Facebook analisys is based on an AJAX request and other things. What you are asking for is too much. You should study a little bit more PHP, AJAX, Javascript and HTML and CSS to better manage the image insertion and urls. You are asking for a script, not for an answer, it's something against SO itself. Anyway the provided functions will be surely usefull to achieve your goal.

Comment: @soju, he updated his answer. It's not my fault. This answer answered the first question.

Comment: @Charlie: no need of bbcode here, or ajax and 'other things', you should study more too

Comment: @soju, provide your own answers instead of bad commenting others. We are all good at commenting, few are good at prove what they are talking about.

Comment: @soju, oh, the one that suggests a general use of a native PHP function? I finally got who i have in front of me. No needs of further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with a proper regular expression to replace the matching pattern and add the HTML tags.